# Have there ever been any cases where someone sued their government for not delivering their passport in a reasonable amount of time?

Tags: canada, case-law, passport, governmental-liability, legal-citation

I am wondering if there have been any cases in Canada that were heard before a court or tribunal, or even if there was any informal dispute that was discussed in any media. Surely many people in the past have had to miss flights and perhaps a lot of money (by missing conferences, or business meetings) due only to the negligence of some civil servant in a passport office who lost the paper work or lacked diligence.

Please pardon me as this is my first question here on Law Stack Exchange! I would be very happy to modify or delete the question if it can be more appropriate!

Comment: Too broad without specifying country.

Comment: @Greendrake: Thanks for the advice. I didn't know that I could specify country. On Academia Stack Exchange they don't want us asking about specific place. I've now specified the country I'm actually interested in (Canada).

Comment: You can just search here: https://www.canlii.org/en/#search/type=decision&text=passport

Comment: Is that really true @Moo? It seems unfair! The person is losing much more than just the passport, they are losing their ability to travel, which means they may miss the family wedding of their daughter! You say "airlines aren't required to cover external costs", but what legislation are you talking about? They are required to pay what the small-claims court decides is fair, and if the plaintiff provides a compelling case that "time" and "money" were lost due to no one's fault but the airline, how on earth is it fair for the airline to walk away scot-free?

Comment: @Moo: EU261 usually compensates for much more than the "direct" costs though! Usually people get more money back than the cost of the original ticket! Except in cases where they are not delayed as long or the distance was not as long; and in those cases the amount of damages will usually also be much less.

Comment: Now you raise a very good point about Easyjet not controlling my "other costs". Easyjet is like a Megabus. If I live in Bristol and have a $1million meeting in London, I have many many options for how to get there. I can pay $10 for a Megabus, or $99 for a train, or $200 for a taxi, or $150 for a train with "cancellation insurance", etc.  For the case of a government employee not showing up to work on the day that they were supposed to be handling my passport renewal application, me missing the meeting is 100% the fault of the government employee, and there is ***no*** other way to get there!

Comment: @Moo. Thanks for explaining things in a bit more detail. The "fixed compensation" is basically to cover "everything else" and most people are happy with it. There's also other options to travel and travel insurance you can get if it's a million dollar meeting. Now I worry that you're making assumptions about this being about last-minute passport applications. It could be Taylor Swift on a concert tour giving 300 performances in 365 days with 0 to 1 days between each performance. It could also be that the applicant paid for the 48-hour service and it took 15 days.

Comment: @Moo: the question was not about UK it was about Canada, and 15-days is not last-minute. We can stop talking about EU261 because there's alternative ways to get to places if a flight gets cancelled. It is impossible to legally leave the country without a passport. Apples and oranges. About missing a concert due to a government not issuing a passport, I think it's debatable.

Comment: Fine, I shall go away then.  Good luck with your question.  But in a lot of cases it's entirely possible to leave a country without a passport, and even enter another country without one.

Comment: @Moo: You've confirmed my hunch that you were trying to be overly pedantic. Yes it is possible to leave a country without a passport. I don't think that brings anything valuable to the discussion unfortunately.